# Merge multiple rows into a single row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I would like to know the best approach to merge data from the following rows into a single row in another view.

These are the results as they are currently displayed;

```
 Type_ID | Client_ID              | PBX_Vendor |
 127     | 090820006311404926326C | Aastra     |
 127     | 090820006311404926326C | Ericsson   |
 127     | 111012237401404926326C | Aastra     |
 127     | 120209287521404926326C | Aastra     |
 127     | 120209287521404926326C | Alcatel    |
```

The following is how I would like to see the data;

```
 Type_ID | Client_ID              | PBX_Vendor       |
 127     | 090820006311404926326C | Aastra, Ericsson |
 127     | 111012237401404926326C | Aastra           |
 127     | 120209287521404926326C | Aastra, Alcatel  |
```

Basically, there are multiple PBX Vendors associated with a Client ID. I need this display in a single row for a helpdesk system.

I have attempted this already with CONCAT, but all I end up with is a single row with over 100 vendors in it that are not specific to a Client_ID.

Any help with be very much appreciated!

Comment: Please select a answer as the right answer when you get a chance - it will help you get quicker / better answers in the future... okay, not really, but we like to say that.

Answer (score 7):

Here's **A** way to do it (also works with 2005):

**Table**

```
DECLARE @table TABLE
    (
      [Type_ID] INT,
      [Client_ID] VARCHAR(50),
      [PBX_Vendor] VARCHAR(50)
    )
```

**Data**

```
INSERT  INTO @table
        SELECT  127,
                '090820006311404926326C',
                'Aastra'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  127,
                '090820006311404926326C',
                'Ericsson'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  127,
                '111012237401404926326C',
                'Aastra'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  127,
                '120209287521404926326C',
                'Aastra'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  127,
                '120209287521404926326C',
                'Alcatel'
```

**Query**

```
SELECT  [Type_ID],
        [Client_ID],
        (
          SELECT    STUFF((
                            SELECT  ',' + [PBX_Vendor]
                            FROM    @table
                            WHERE   [Client_ID] = tbl.[Client_ID]
                                    AND [Type_ID] = tbl.[Type_ID]
                            GROUP BY [PBX_Vendor]
                            ORDER BY [PBX_Vendor]
                          FOR
                            XML PATH('')
                          ), 1, 1, '')
        ) PBX_Vendor
FROM    @table tbl
GROUP BY [Type_ID],
        [Client_ID]
```

**Result**

```
Type_ID     Client_ID               PBX_Vendor
127         090820006311404926326C  Aastra,Ericsson
127         111012237401404926326C  Aastra
127         120209287521404926326C  Aastra,Alcatel
```

Comment: Dan Im afraid I cant seem to get that to work with my existing code. I must add that Im using Sql Management Studio to devlop this as im not SQL trained.

Comment: Any other suggestions or advice?

Comment: Managed to convert the above to my tables, but the error im getting is "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ', ' to data type int". THis must be because I already have a lookup apllied from my original view.

Comment: Sorry, I would have to see all of the data to figure out what you did.  I wrote the example in SSMS as well - it's what we all use :)  Are you inserting your data into my variable table?  If so... don't.  Just change the "FROM @table" to your table in your database in the query (two places).

Comment: Dan, thanks for your help so far. I will try and break this down for you a bit more:

Comment: Type_ID | Client_ID              | Code_ID    |Description   |
 127     | 090820006311404926326C | 10         |Aastra        |
 127     | 090820006311404926326C | 8          |Ericsson      |
 127     | 111012237401404926326C | 10         |Aastra        |
 127     | 120209287521404926326C | 10         |Aastra        |
 127     | 120209287521404926326C | 7          |Alcatel       |

Comment: Code_ID contains the INT reference that is then looked up against another table for the name. SO i need to run the query against the original table and then run a look up so it doesnt just bunch 8, 6 together. Not that it works anyway as the error im getting is Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ',' to data type int.

Comment: Sounds like you have a problem with your "lookup" and it has nothing to do with your question.  "Don't scope creep on me, bro!" :)  Did you change the `@table` to your view / table?

Comment: Yes, still got the error. I will try removing the lookup first.

Answer (score 0):

Dan, I have managed to get this working using your original Ideas with some modifications. Although I cannot save it as a view as I understand that you cannot save DECLARES as VIEWS;

```
DECLARE @table TABLE
    (
      [Type_ID] INT,
      [Client_ID] VARCHAR(50),
      [PBX_Vendor] VARCHAR(50)
    )

INSERT  INTO @table
        SELECT  dbo.AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl.Type_Id, dbo.AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl.Client_Id, dbo.AMGR_User_Field_Defs_Tbl.Description AS PBX_Vendor
            FROM    dbo.AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl INNER JOIN
                    dbo.AMGR_User_Field_Defs_Tbl ON dbo.AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl.Type_Id = dbo.AMGR_User_Field_Defs_Tbl.Type_Id AND 
                    dbo.AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl.Code_Id = dbo.AMGR_User_Field_Defs_Tbl.Code_Id
            WHERE     (dbo.AMGR_User_Fields_Tbl.Type_Id = 127)

SELECT  [Type_ID],
        [Client_ID],
        (
          SELECT    STUFF((
                            SELECT  ', ' + [PBX_Vendor]
                            FROM    @table
                            WHERE   [Client_ID] = tbl.[Client_ID]
                                    AND [Type_ID] = tbl.[Type_ID]
                            GROUP BY [PBX_Vendor]
                            ORDER BY [PBX_Vendor]
                          FOR
                            XML PATH('')
                          ), 1, 1, '')
        ) PBX_Vendor
FROM    @table tbl
GROUP BY [Type_ID],
        [Client_ID]
```

Comment: don't forget to mark my answer as the selected answer (2 years later)

Comment: don't forget to mark my answer as the selected answer (5 years later)