# SQL Server : join and append columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a SQL question, and hope someone could help me or give me some pointers. Much appreciated.

I have two tables: A and B.

- A has columns `ID` which is the primary key field, and `NAME`
- B has columns `DUPID`, `NAME` and `ID` which is the primary key

The relationship between A and B is in B, the `DUPID` contains certain values of `A.ID`, and the request is to append distinct `B.NAME` value to `A.NAME` separated by semi-colon based on join `A.ID = B.DUPID`..

Maybe my explanation isn't clear, here is a simple example.

```
A                                  B
ID  NAME                           DUPID      NAME
1   null                            1             John
2   null                            1             John
3   null                            1             Mark
4   null                            3             Luke
5   null                            3             Luke
                                    3             Luke
                                    3             Matthew
```

So eventually, I will need to update table A, and make it look like below

```
A
ID      NAME
1        John;Mark
2        null
3        Luke;Matthew
4        null
5        null
```

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553198/merge-multiple-rows-into-a-single-row/10553404#10553404

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike `MySQL`, `SQL Server` doesn't have a built-in function to do that. But you can still simulate it by using `CROSS APPLY` and `FOR XML PATH('')`

```
SELECT  a.ID, 
        SUBSTRING(d.NameList,1, LEN(d.NameList) - 1) Names
FROM    a
        CROSS APPLY
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT [NAME] + '; ' 
            FROM  B 
            WHERE A.ID = B.DupID 
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ) D (NameList)
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/85cd8/4)