# Concatenate rows from a complex select in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, concatenation

RDBMS is SQL Server 2008.

I have 3 tables. To simplify they look like this:

`NominationOrder` table:

```
NominationOrderId | NominationId
         1        |      5
         2        |      9
```

`NominationOrderItem` table:

```
NominationOrderItemId | NominationOrderId | GiftId
           1          |         1         |    6
           2          |         1         |    3
           3          |         1         |    9
```

`Gift` table:

```
GiftId | GiftName |
  3    |   TVSet
  6    |  TabletPC
  9    | LittlePonny
```

So, there's some `Nomination`. Each `Nomination` may have 1 `Nomination Order`. Each `Nomination Order` may have many `Nomination Order Items`, each of them references to some `Gift` from this order.

I'm making a report for Reporting Services and I need to display data about each nomination with `Gift` in a single row, showing `Gift` names concatenated.

Currently it looks like this:

```
NominationId | NominationOrderId |    GiftName
      5      |          1        |     TVSet     
      5      |          1        |    TabletPC    
      5      |          1        |   LittlePonny
```

I need it to look like this:

```
NominationId | NominationOrderId |           GiftName
      5      |          1        |   TVSet, TabletPC, LittlePonny
```

A simplified example of current SQL query:

```
  select 
    nn.NominationId
    ,n_o.NominationOrderId
    ,g.name GiftName
from dbo.Nomination nn
    LEFT JOIN dbo.NominationOrder n_o ON n_o.NominationId = nn.NominationId
    LEFT JOIN dbo.NominationOrderItem noi ON noi.NominationOrderId = n_o.NominationOrderId
    left join dbo.Gift g on g.GiftId = noi.GiftId
```

How can I rewrite it to make an output in a single string and concatenate gift names?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @Mureinik, it's MSSQL 2008, thx for the notice!

Comment: Where is the fourth table?`Nomination`?

Comment: How many gifts can be for every `NominationId` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553198/merge-multiple-rows-into-a-single-row/10553404#10553404

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CTE :

```
WITH cteTbl (NominationId, NominationOrderId, GiftName) AS ( Your Query here)
```

And then concatenate all rows with the same `NominationId` and `NominationOrderId` with `FOR XML PATH('')` and after that replace the first comma `,` with `STUFF`:

```
SELECT t.NominationId
     , t.NominationOrderId
     , STUFF( ( SELECT ', ' + GiftName
                FROM cteTbl
                WHERE NominationId = t.NominationId
                  AND NominationOrderId = t.NominationOrderId
                ORDER BY GiftName DESC
                FOR XML PATH('') ), 1, 1, '')
FROM cteTbl t 
GROUP BY t.NominationId
       , t.NominationOrderId
```

#### [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/95152/5)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT result.NominationId, Substring(result.Gifts,3,Len(result.Gifts) - 3)
FROM (
    SELECT 
    NominationId, 
    (SELECT ', ' + CAST(g.GiftName AS varchar(MAX)) 
        FROM NominationOrder i 
        INNER JOIN NominationOrderItem noi on i.NominationOrderId = noi.NominationOrderId
        INNER JOIN Gift g on noi.GiftId = g.GiftId
        WHERE i.NominationId = n.NominationId
        FOR XML PATH (''))
         AS Gifts
    FROM NominationOrder n
    GROUP BY NominationId
) result
```